# How to find the roots of an equation for different wave numbers?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have a equation `nn` which is a function of `t` and `k`. I want to find the maximum of the equation for different wave numbers in a fixed range.

so far I tried the following,

```
nn =  -k^2 Sin[t] Exp[-2 k^2 Sin[t/2]^2];
i2k[i_] = 1/2 (i - 1) ;
data2 = Table[
   nn /. k -> -i2k[i] /. t -> t - 2 // Evaluate, {i, 3, 10}]; 
dxx2[t_] = D[data2, t ];
max = t /. FindRoot[dxx2[t], {t, #}] & /@ Range[20.72, 20.80, 0.01] //
    Select[20.72 < # < 20.80 &] // 
  DeleteDuplicatesBy[Round[#, 10^-4] &]
data2 /. t -> max // Evaluate
```

However, the number the equation does not match with the numbers of variable in the `FindRoot` and I can understand why, but I can not implement what I want.`dxx[t_]` contains all the dervatives. I need to find the root of each `dxx[t_]` in `Range[20.72, 20.80, 0.01]` and put it in the main equation to calculate the maximums.

I appreciate it if you could help me.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
nn = Function[{k, t}, -k^2 Sin[t] Exp[-2 k^2 Sin[t/2]^2]];

(* list of functions i=3...10*)
funs = Table[nn[1/2 (i - 1), t - 2], {i, 3, 10}]
pic=Plot[funs, {t, 20  , 21}]  (* time range 20 <t<21 *)
```

[image]

```
maxis = Map[NMaximize[{#, 20 < t < 21}, t] &, funs]
Show[pic, Graphics[Map[Point[{t /. #[[2]], #[[1]]}] &, maxis]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

nn = -k^2 Sin[t] Exp[-2 k^2 Sin[t/2]^2];
i2k[i_] = 1/2 (i - 1);
data2 = Table[nn /. k -> -i2k[i] /. t -> t - 2 // Evaluate, {i, 3, 10}];
```

The exact values are

```
(max = Maximize[{#, 19 < t < 21}, t] & /@ data2 // Simplify)

(* {{-E^(-2 Sin[
      2 ArcTan[Sqrt[5 + 2 Sqrt[5] + 2 Sqrt[11 + 5 Sqrt[5]]]]]^2) Sin[
    4 ArcTan[Sqrt[5 + 2 Sqrt[5] + 2 Sqrt[11 + 5 Sqrt[5]]]]], {t -> 
    2 + 4 π + 
     4 ArcTan[Sqrt[5 + 2 Sqrt[5] + 2 Sqrt[11 + 5 Sqrt[5]]]]}}, {-(9/4)
     E^(-(9/2) Sin[
     2 ArcTan[Sqrt[10 + Sqrt[85] + 2 Sqrt[46 + 5 Sqrt[85]]]]]^2)
    Sin[4 ArcTan[Sqrt[
      10 + Sqrt[85] + 2 Sqrt[46 + 5 Sqrt[85]]]]], {t -> 
    2 + 4 π + 
     4 ArcTan[Sqrt[
       10 + Sqrt[85] + 2 Sqrt[46 + 5 Sqrt[85]]]]}}, {-4 E^(-8 Sin[
     2 ArcTan[Sqrt[17 + 2 Sqrt[65] + 2 Sqrt[137 + 17 Sqrt[65]]]]]^2)
    Sin[4 ArcTan[Sqrt[
      17 + 2 Sqrt[65] + 2 Sqrt[137 + 17 Sqrt[65]]]]], {t -> 
    2 + 4 π + 
     4 ArcTan[Sqrt[
       17 + 2 Sqrt[65] + 2 Sqrt[137 + 17 Sqrt[65]]]]}}, {-(25/4)
     E^(-(25/2) Sin[
     2 ArcTan[Sqrt[26 + Sqrt[629] + 2 Sqrt[326 + 13 Sqrt[629]]]]]^2)
    Sin[4 ArcTan[Sqrt[
      26 + Sqrt[629] + 2 Sqrt[326 + 13 Sqrt[629]]]]], {t -> 
    2 + 4 π + 
     4 ArcTan[Sqrt[
       26 + Sqrt[629] + 
        2 Sqrt[326 + 13 Sqrt[629]]]]}}, {-9 E^(-18 Sin[
     2 ArcTan[Sqrt[37 + 10 Sqrt[13] + 2 Sqrt[667 + 185 Sqrt[13]]]]]^2)
    Sin[4 ArcTan[Sqrt[
      37 + 10 Sqrt[13] + 2 Sqrt[667 + 185 Sqrt[13]]]]], {t -> 
    2 + 4 π + 
     4 ArcTan[Sqrt[
       37 + 10 Sqrt[13] + 2 Sqrt[667 + 185 Sqrt[13]]]]}}, {-(49/4)
     E^(-(49/2) Sin[
     2 ArcTan[Sqrt[
       50 + Sqrt[2405] + 2 Sqrt[1226 + 25 Sqrt[2405]]]]]^2)
    Sin[4 ArcTan[Sqrt[
      50 + Sqrt[2405] + 2 Sqrt[1226 + 25 Sqrt[2405]]]]], {t -> 
    2 + 4 π + 
     4 ArcTan[Sqrt[
       50 + Sqrt[2405] + 
        2 Sqrt[1226 + 25 Sqrt[2405]]]]}}, {-16 E^(-32 Sin[
     2 ArcTan[Sqrt[
       65 + 10 Sqrt[41] + 2 Sqrt[2081 + 325 Sqrt[41]]]]]^2)
    Sin[4 ArcTan[Sqrt[
      65 + 10 Sqrt[41] + 2 Sqrt[2081 + 325 Sqrt[41]]]]], {t -> 
    2 + 4 π + 
     4 ArcTan[Sqrt[
       65 + 10 Sqrt[41] + 2 Sqrt[2081 + 325 Sqrt[41]]]]}}, {-(81/4)
     E^(-(81/2) Sin[
     2 ArcTan[Sqrt[
       82 + Sqrt[6565] + 2 Sqrt[3322 + 41 Sqrt[6565]]]]]^2)
    Sin[4 ArcTan[Sqrt[
      82 + Sqrt[6565] + 2 Sqrt[3322 + 41 Sqrt[6565]]]]], {t -> 
    2 + 4 π + 
     4 ArcTan[Sqrt[82 + Sqrt[6565] + 2 Sqrt[3322 + 41 Sqrt[6565]]]]}}} *)
```

The approximate values are

```
max // N

(* {{0.536563, {t -> 19.945}}, {0.860824, {t -> 20.2097}}, {1.17579, 
    {t -> 20.3605}}, {1.48632, {t -> 20.4551}}, {1.7945, 
    {t -> 20.5194}}, {2.10131, {t -> 20.5658}}, {2.40724, 
    {t -> 20.6009}}, {2.71259, {t -> 20.6283}}} *)
```